# The minimum input value depends on the second input

Tags: javascript, html

I try to enter a minimum value depending on the second value.

**desc:** if the start field is 12:00, then the end field cannot enter less than 12:00

**I tried:**

```js
const ends = [...tr.querySelectorAll('.end')];

const getMin = timeStr => {
    const [hour, min] = timeStr.split(':');
    return +hour * 60 + +min;
};

[...tr.querySelectorAll('.start')]
    .forEach((el, i) => {
    el.addEventListener('change', e => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        const end = ends[i];
        end.setAttribute('min', value);

        if (!end.value || getMin(end.value) < getMin(value)) {
            end.value = value;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
    <td class="InputsForUserColor1">
      <input class="start" type="time" id="id_start_1" />
    </td>

    <td class="InputsForUserColor2">
      <input class="end" type="time" id="id_end_1" max="23:59" />
    </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: What isn't working? And where have you defined `tr`?

Comment: What's `.end` and `.start` inside `tr`?? There is no element in HTML code which has class name `end` and `start`.

Comment: @Ajay Varghese i Update

Comment: @ZombieDivision Check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have `.start` class for start Input and `.end` class for end Input.
Just try attaching an `onchange` to get the value of startInput and set it as the `min` of the end Input. Check this [pen](https://codepen.io/z-/pen/zYxdRQy).

```
startInput.addEventListener("change", e => {
    endEls[index].setAttribute("min", e.target.value);
});
```